# ZFS beginner questions. Activating passkey, etc

Tags: backup, disk-encryption, zfsonlinux

I am on a journey of migrating a Windows/NTFS backup to Ubuntu and natively encrypted ZFS. As a Windows veteran with zero Linux experience, most guides seem like Greek to me. Successful progress yet:

1. Installed OpenZFS via `sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux`
2. Created a raidz pool: `sudo zpool create -f Backup raidz3 /dev/sda /dev/sdb` etc...
3. Installed Dolphin to locate the pool in `/Backup`
4. Created a dataset inside the pool: `sudo zfs create -o encryption=on -o keyformat=passphrase Backup/Backup`

Here I am kind of stuck:

1. The OS never asks for the pool/dataset password. All needed to mount is either `sudo zfs mount Backup` + root password, or logging in.
2. What is the difference between a pool and a dataset? The pool created a ZFS file system for me.
3. Is it possible to use the folder `/Backup` rather than `/Backup/Backup`? Is it recommended?
4. What kind of (beginner friendly) maintenance routines would one run without risking to mess it up? This ZFS setup is all about redundancy and bit-rot protection.

I have looked through several threads about this, but I am completely lost around the commands and variables.
All help appreciated. :)

Comment: It would help those trying to help you if you could specify the "several threads" you have looked through so there is not duplication.

Comment: A "_pool_" can be thought of as the array itself, or the collection of disks. A "_dataset_" is an independent box / filesystem on that pool, and can be hierarchical. Each pool has a dataset at its root. You've not provided a `keylocation` option, which means that it'll probably be inherited from the parent dataset, and in this situation it _should_ prompt you... what does `zfs get -r keylocation Backup` show? ([ref](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ZFS#Native_encryption))

Comment: @T.Smoerti - Edit your question instead of submitting commentary

Answer (score 1):

What you did looks all correct. If I understand correctly, your only problem is that you don’t have to enter a password to mount the encrypted dataset.

Did you reboot yet?

ZFS keeps dataset keys in memory indefinitely, until you unload them or export the pool. You can use the `zfs unload-key` command to explicitly unload the key of a dataset:

```
zfs unload-key tank/my/dataset
```

This command only works with unmounted datasets. You will then find that `zfs mount` no longer works. You need to issue a `zfs load-key` command first.

If you want a pool with an encrypted root dataset, you can create it like this:

```
zpool create -O encryption=on -O keyformat=passphrase mypool /dev/disk/by-id/…
```

When you import this pool, the root dataset will be unmounted until you do `zfs load-key`, `zfs mount`.

Encrypting a dataset after creation involves `zfs send` and `zfs receive`. If you can, create a new encrypted dataset instead. Much less of a hassle.